# parameters are not setting to managed property in jsf primefaces

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

I am trying to pass parameters from UI to service which is managed bean. Values are not getting set to bean properties

```
   <ui>
    <p:dialog header="Account Search" widget-var="account Search">
    <h:inputText id="account Name" value="#{accountSub.request.accountName}"/>
    <p:commandButton id="btnSearch"  update="">
    <h:inputText id="account Name" value="#{accountSub.request.accountNumber}"/>
    <p:commandButton id="btnSearch"  update="">
    <p:ajax event="click" listener="#{accountSub.process}"           update="@widgetVar(resultPanel)">
    </p:dialog>
    </ui>
```

**Managed Bean**

```
 @ManagedBean
    @VieweScoped
    public class AccountSub {

    private Account request;
   //getter and setter for same

    public void process(){
    // process logic goes here.
    }
    }

    class Account{

   private String accountName;
   private String accountNumber;
   //getter and setter
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of errors in the example.

1. Id of input component is not valid. You should not include space.
2. Ajax Event 'click' is not supported

Use form element as below.

`<h:form>
    <p:dialog header="Basic Dialog" widgetVar="dlg1" minHeight="40">
         <h:inputText id="name" value="#{accountSub.request.accountName}"/>
         <h:inputText id="number" value="#{accountSub.request.accountNumber}"/>
         <p:commandButton id="btnSearch"  actionListener="#{accountSub.process}">Click</p:commandButton>
    </p:dialog>
</h:form>`